How to inline astro components in a markdown page
I'm looking for a way to "inject" some generated content in the middle of a markdown file in Astro.
I have been extensively reading the docs, and I can't find the primitives I was expecting to do that.
Ideally I want to import the markdown file, parse it, get each section and render it at will.
However that is not possible. Then I found markdoc that allows to "inline" astro components inside markdown.
Not exactly what I wanted, because I no longer have a markdown document, but it is not far from having a "markdown document with a placeholder".
Markdoc files can only be used within content collections (I don't understand this limitation), and it feels a bit overkill to create a collection for a single file, but  it may be the only way.
Is there any other possible way to achieve this? Will a Astro component within Markdoc be able to fetch content from another collection?

Sounds like you're looking for https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/integrations-guide/mdx/ ?

That is definitely the simplest solution to my problem. I hoped to keep the original file as simple as possible, ideally in markdown but it seems it will require too awkward workarounds. MDX is more popular than Marcdoc, so it's maybe a safer bet
